# AbsListView on Samsung Galaxy's logcat running Android 4.3 JellyBean

Tags: samsung, 4.3-jelly-bean, logging

I've been having an issue on my Galaxy S4 following the 4.3 update whereby it will occasionally reboot the phone then go into a reboot loop. If connected to a charge the loop will stop and the battery will be fine (e.g. at 80%).

Now one thing I've noticed in trying to diagnose this via logcat is that the following message:

```
13:37:54.600 AbsListView unregisterIRListener() is called
```

occurs about 26 times a second. Is this normal behavior? If not how can I find and eliminate the cause?

Comment: I observer similar problems with my S4 (after 4.3 update, random crashes and then boot loops). I am not expert in Android internals, but the "AbsListView" seems like some image resolution issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16445635/galaxy-s4-and-maybe-all-hd-phones-out-of-memory-error-inflating-layout My guess is it has nothing to do with it. Still your question is valid!

Comment: For others wondering - my problems disappeared after servicing the phone in official Samsung repair shop. So maybe the 4.3 upgrade was just a coincidence. The report from repair indicated battery being replaced and software upgrade (but I don't believe the last one, as exact the same build version is reported in Settings).

Comment: From [this question on SO](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/60629/unstable-s4-abslistview), it seems an issue affecting some of Samsung devices, and looks like a debug log. Nothing serious.

Answer (score -1):

try to replace in the adapeter:

```
view = context.LayoutInflater.Inflate(Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleSpinnerItem, null);
```

with

```
view = context.LayoutInflater.Inflate(Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleSpinnerItem, parent, false);
```

Ref#: [this link](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/16182/problem-with-android-4-4-2)

Comment: Sorry Chris but I no longer own the phone this query was about. Also I wouldn't have known how to implement your answer in any case.

Comment: No problem .. I post this answer maybe it will be helpful for the new users too. Thanks for your comment :)

Comment: Sorry, but this site is not about Android programming. Your answer will be helpful for Android programmer, but for end-user, they cannot do anything to solve this issue.